# Wildcard expansion doesn't happen when Bash script invoked from cron under macOS

Tags: bash, cron, macos

I have a Mac mini running macOS Monterey, and it has InfluxDB running in a Docker container. I'm trying to set up a nightly cronjob via a shell script I'm calling to back the data up, zip it, and only keep the seven most recent backups. The backing up part works perfectly regardless of whether I'm running it manually or via cron, but the bit that's giving me grief is in cron for the shell expansion to get the current number of backup files so I can keep only the most recent ones.

I've stripped the whole thing down to just trying to figure out how to get shell expansion working at all under cron, with zero luck.

The simplest thing I've come up with is this, which behaves (correctly) as the following when running it manually:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'BACKUPS=(/Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/*) && echo "Number of backups: ${#BACKUPS[*]}" && echo "Oldest backup: ${BACKUPS[0]}"'
Number of backups: 10
Oldest backup: /Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/2022-04-12_00-30.zip
```

If I put that exact same thing into cron, I get the following:

```
Number of backups: 1
Oldest backup: /Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/*
```

I know by default cron uses `/bin/sh` and I've tried setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of my `crontab` as well, to no avail (though I wouldn't have thought that would have any effect if I'm either calling a script directly with a shebang of `#!/bin/bash`?).

Am I missing something obvious here?

**[EDIT]**
To clarify things a bit, I'm currently testing solely with cron and have excluded running an actual script file just to get down to the minimum possible scenario, the relevant `crontab` entry looks like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'BACKUPS=(/Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/*) && echo Number of backups: ${#BACKUPS[*]} && echo Oldest backup: ${BACKUPS[0]}'
```

If I copy that exact same line (`/bin/bash -c 'BACKUPS=(/Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/*) && echo Number of backups: ${#BACKUPS[*]} && echo Oldest backup: ${BACKUPS[0]}'`) into my terminal, it works as expected and it lists ten files and shows the oldest backup. When it's executed by `cron`, the shell expansion hasn't occurred and it's taken the `BACKUPS` variable as the literal string `/Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/*`.

Comment: Is your home folder encrypted? Is it unencrypted when the cronjob runs?

Comment: The whole disk is encrypted using [FileVault](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837) and it's unlocked at boot when I put my password in, so no issues there. :) I've been testing by just having the thing run every minute.

Comment: If you put the same commands in your backup script in Cron, do you get the expected output?

Comment: When you say "script" do you mean that the commands are in an executable file, and you're executing the file from cron?

Comment: @muru No, I get the output I pasted above ("If I put the exact same thing into cron..."), where it's just taken the path with the asterisk at the end as the literal path and hasn't done any expansion.

Comment: @dg99 Yep, that's correct.

Comment: @VirtualWolf so the very script that's able to create a file in `/Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups/` is not able to list files in it?

Comment: @muru You absolute legend, I figured I'd just double-check that to be sure, and changing my crontab entry to `/bin/bash -c 'ls -tr /Users/virtualwolf/Documents/InfluxDB_Backups` resulted in an "Operation not permitted" error! I need to [give `/usr/sbin/cron` full disk access](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/), and now everything works a treat.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how those backups were being created, though.

Comment: You used the `macos` tag - that's good! But you probably should mention `macos` in your Title line also. There are many "non-standard" things like this in macos.

Comment: @Seamus Yeah that's a good call, I've updated the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to @muru's excellent questioning, it turns out this was nothing to do with Cron and shell expansion at all, and was instead a case of the `/usr/sbin/cron` executable not having full disk access in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy.

I unlocked the preference pane, went into "Full Disk Access", clicked the + and hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the Go To Folder dialog, popped in `/usr/sbin` and found `cron` and added it, and now everything works a treat.