# Scheduled cron job not running on MacOS

Tags: bash, cron, python, macos

Here is my crontab.

```
3 13 * * 1-5 * * * * * /Users/smveerap/cron.sh >/tmp/cronStdout.log 2>/tmp/cronStderr.log
0 12 * * 1-5 * * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 ~/git/bashFiles/gitUpdate.py >/tmp/cronStdout.log 2>/tmp/cronStderr.log
```

I have tried my luck to run my script ***gitUpdate.py*** by running the script directly as well as running it via ***cron.sh*** bash script. Both python and bash scripts have 755 permissions. The contents of ***cron.sh*** is as below.

```
echo "cron run"
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 ~/git/bashFiles/gitUpdate.py
```

I still don't see any conlole log outputs in ***/tmp/cronStdout.log*** making me think that the script has not run.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The format takes five time specifiers. You have **ten** on each line.

Comment: Apart from the issue with the strangely formatted schedule [pointed out by Paul_Pendant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699924/scheduled-cron-job-not-running-on-macos#comment1323175_699924), have you given the cron daemon full disk access? [Wildcard expansion doesn't happen when Bash script invoked from cron under macOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699536)

Comment: Thanks guys! Both of your suggestions worked.